# show an output of a python process in VB.NET

Tags: python, vb.net

Hello what am trying to do is run a python script and while the script is running I show the output in a text box in VB.NET so i don't wait until the script is finished no, while it's running.

Answer (score 2):

If your python script outputs to the standard output stream, then you can read it fairly easily by redirecting the standard output of the process to your application.  When you create a process, you can set properties on the `Process.StartInfo` object which will instruct it to redirect the output.  You can then read the output from the process asynchronously via the `OutputDataReceived` event that is raised by the process object as new output is received.

For instance, if you were to create a class like this:

```
Public Class CommandExecutor
    Implements IDisposable

    Public Event OutputRead(ByVal output As String)

    Private WithEvents _process As Process

    Public Sub Execute(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal arguments As String)
        If _process IsNot Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Already watching process")
        End If
        _process = New Process()
        _process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath
        _process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        _process.Start()
        _process.BeginOutputReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub _process_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles _process.OutputDataReceived
        If _process.HasExited Then
            _process.Dispose()
            _process = Nothing
        End If
        RaiseEvent OutputRead(e.Data)
    End Sub

    Private disposedValue As Boolean = False
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                If _process IsNot Nothing Then
                    _process.Kill()
                    _process.Dispose()
                    _process = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents _commandExecutor As New CommandExecutor()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        _commandExecutor.Execute("MyPythonScript.exe", "")
    End Sub

    Private Sub _commandExecutor_OutputRead(ByVal output As String) Handles _commandExecutor.OutputRead
        Me.Invoke(New processCommandOutputDelegate(AddressOf processCommandOutput), output)
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub processCommandOutputDelegate(ByVal output As String)
    Private Sub processCommandOutput(ByVal output As String)
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + output
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        _commandExecutor.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```